# Retrieve Facebook Data using ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, .net-4.5

I am trying to use Facebook Authentication on my website which I have built using Visual Studio 2013 .Net framework 4.5 Web Forms (Note: I am not using MVC).

Now, I am able to authenticate users via Facebook but after successful login, I want more user information (email, DOB, friends etc) but for that I will need access code to use Facebook graph API. I saw a ton of examples of how to get the access token using MVC but could not find one example of how to do it using Web Forms application. The return url does not return the access code nor does it return the Code to get the access code.

There is also an interesting comment on the Microsoft website :

*"The ASP.NET MVC API—specifically the OAuthWeb­Security class—addresses the authentication scenario nicely, but it doesn’t cover interacting with the social provider beyond getting a display name. It also integrates well with the simple membership provider of Web Pages for storing Twitter and Facebook user names locally."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198238.aspx

So I am assuming that holds true even for Web Forms.

I also have the FB SDK installed that requires access token to retrieve data from Facebook.

So the question remains how do I get the Facebook Access Token after user logs in successfully?